# How to query for text and numbers in Postgres inside a jsonb using indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, jsonb

I have a Postgres table named "base" with a `jsonb` field called "addresses" which stores multiple addresses for the same user.

Here is the table structure:

```sql
create table base(name text, addresses jsonb);

insert into base(name, addresses) values('John', '[{"zip":"01431000","state":"SP","number":100,"street1":"Avenida Brasil","city_name":"São Paulo"},{"zip":"01310900","state":"SP","number":200,"street1":"Avenida Paulista","city_name":"São Paulo"}]');
insert into base(name, addresses) values('Doe', '[{"zip":"01332000","state":"SP","number":250,"street1":"Rua Itapeva","city_name":"São Paulo"}]');
```

I'm trying to search for specific row containing an address using combination of "street1" and "number" keys using gin index on key "street1".

Here is the structure of the `jsonb` field:

```json
[
  {
    "zip":"01431000",
    "state":"SP",
    "number":100,
    "street1":"Avenida Brasil",
    "city_name":"São Paulo",
  },
  {
    "zip":"01310900",
    "state":"SP",
    "number":200,
    "street1":"Avenida Paulista",
    "city_name":"São Paulo",
  },
]
```

How I would be able to search, for example, for a row containing: `to_tsquery('simple', 'paulista')` and `number = 200`? I need to be able to search for partial "street1" name.

I have a index for searching by "zip" and "number":

```
create index base_addresses_idx on base using gin (addresses jsonb_path_ops);
```

And the search is really fast using this query:
`select * from table. where addresses @> '[{"zip":"01431000","number":100}]';`

But I am not able to query for partial "street1" name (using tsvector) and a specific number.

PS: I am using PostgreSQL 15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to create a materialized view with the expanded addresses field:

```sql
create materialized view address as (
  select
    base_id,
    address,
    to_tsvector('simple', concat_ws(' ', jsonb_extract_path_text(address, 'street1'), jsonb_extract_path_text(address, 'number'))) as tsvector_address
  from (
    select
      base.id,
      jsonb_array_elements(base.addresses) as address
    from base
  ) as address
);
```

Then, I have created those indexes:

```sql
create index address_id_idx on address using btree (base_id);
create index address_address_idx on address using gin (tsvector_address);
```

This way, I can query easily with an inner join between `base` and `address` using tsvector on `street1` and `number` keys:

```sql
select distinct on (base.id) base.*
from base

inner join address
on base.id = address.base_id
where address.tsvector_address @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'query')
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries should be able to do this. For each row in base, use `jsonb_array_elements()` to locate all dictionaries containing a value in `street1` like your substring. Then from those, find any containing your other condition. Put this in a `WHERE EXISTS` clause by selecting `1` at each occurrence.

```
SELECT *
FROM base
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (
    SELECT addr
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(addresses) AS addr
    WHERE addr->>'street1' ILIKE '%Paulista%'
  ) AS filtered
  WHERE filtered.addr->>'number' = '200'
);
```

Comment: I have edited the content of my question with the table structure. What I need is to be able to search for partial "street1" name and a specific number. I need to return the rows which have this information. I have tried this example but it only works if I know the exact name of the Street, not the partial information.

Comment: I have tried using the %% (ilike) operator from the example you provided but it returned no results. My idea is to do some kind of indexing on this specific key "street1" using tsvector. But i am starting to think it is not possible

Comment: @andreyfarias You're correct, that was my mistake. So sorry, try the updated version I just created.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it has the problem I had expected. This query leads to false matches. For example: it will return the a if it have one address with the correct "street1" and another address with the correct "number". I think I will need to resort to something like a materialized view of this jsonb.

Comment: @andreyfarias I just built a custom table to test and verified the latest answer does not suffer from that issue. I was able to select only the correct records.

Comment: Thanks for helping, @MrChadMWood but in the end I opted to go with a materialized view. I have posted an answer detailing it.